# What do I need to file as far as taxes if I give out a one time commission to a friend

Tags: united-states, expenses, commission

I have an LLC and I own a small recruiting side business. One of the people I "placed" at a company was through a friend. I paid that friend $3000 for his services or helping me find a candidate.

My question is do I need to serve him with a w9/1099 (or something like that) so that I can write of the $3000 as an expense? He doesn't have a business or anything like that, just a friend of mine that helped me out.

Comment: it's just an ordinary 1099.  makes little difference "what" the job was.

Comment: @Fattie there are multiple 1099 forms.  In this case it'll probably be a 1099-MISC.

Comment: @RonJohn - fair enough, good one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-misc-miscellaneous-income), the requirement is that all payments of $600 or more must be reported on a 1099-MISC.  The relevant section is "services performed by someone who is not your employee".

Your friend's [Taxpayer Identification Number](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/individual-taxpayer-identification-number) (TIN) will likely be his Social Security Number but it could also be a TIN, in either case it will be the same number he uses when filing his taxes. If this was through your friends business, it would be the businesses [Employer Identification Number](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/apply-for-an-employer-identification-number-ein-online) (EIN).

Note:  I'm assuming that this is the United States, as you mention a 1099.  If you are located elsewhere, please revise the question.